# How to locate the WSDL file in Azure web site?

Tags: web-services, wcf, azure, wsdl

I've created a web application that runs a web service (WCF). The source code is long gone but I just checked that the app itself is still up and running. Given that I have the address to the service (*something.azurewebsites.com*) and the name of one of the methods exposed (parameterless *Ping*), how can I learn the location of the WSDL file?

As far I recall, I've exposed it the most common way, the publish file fetched from the suggestion on Azure portal. I'd like to just call the method *Ping* to verify something, so rebuilding a whole new service seems a bit overkill.

Suggestions on what the exact URL might be? Alternatively, suggestions on a tool to sniff that up?

Comment: Do you have a .svc file in your web application? If so then try to use it like something.azurewebsite.com/service1.svc and that page should show the url for wsdl

Comment: @Rajesh Yeah, that'd be great but note the part "*source code is long gone*". I don't have it anymore and I'm trying to be lazy and not rewrite it. I only need to call the service and **that** has been running well ever since I deployed it, eaons ago. I'd need a way to check what service name that is used (the part prior SVC).

Comment: Have you had a look at FTP to inspect the code deployed on Azure? You might be able to look there to find the ".svc" file.

Comment: @BrianSherwin Well, I've tried accessing the address *ftp://something.azurewebsite.net* but that didn't give me much. I only got a runt-time error and not even a specified one. I'm guessing I didn't open for the site to publish the error messages...

Comment: Go to the Azure portal and find the FTP address for your "something.azurewebsite.net". Then use an FTP program to connect to the server and browse the files. This way you might be able to find the ".svc" file. For that matter, you might be able to download all of your code and use a tool like Reflector to view the .Net compiled code.

Comment: @BrianSherwin Why not post that as a reply so it can be marked as an answer and maybe voted on?

Comment: Added as an answer. Hadn't thought of it as an answer when I initially was asking what you had tried. Hoping it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Azure portal and find the FTP address for your "something.azurewebsite.net". Then use an FTP program to connect to the server and browse the files. This way you might be able to find the ".svc" file. For that matter, you might be able to download all of your code and use a tool like Reflector to view the .Net compiled code.